# How do I match single ID's in one data frame to multiples of the IDs in another data frame in R?

Tags: r

For a project at work, I need to generate a table from a list of proposal ids, and a table with more data about some of those proposals (called "awards"). I'm having trouble with the match() function; the data in the "awards" table often has several rows that use the same ID, while the proposals frame has only one copy of each ID.  From what I've tried, R ignores multiple rows and only returns the first match, when I need all of them.  I haven't been able to find anything in documentation or through searches that helps me, though I have been having difficulty phrasing the right question.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#R CODE to add awards data on proposals to new data spreadsheet
#read tab delimited files
Awards=read.delim("O:/testing.txt",as.is=T)
Proposals=read.delim("O:/test.txt",as.is=T)

#match IDs from both spreadsheets
Proposals$TotalAwarded=Awards$TotalAwarded([match(Proposals$IDs,Awards$IDs)]),

write.table(Proposals,"O:/tested.txt",quote=F,row.names=F,sep="\t")
```

This does exactly what I want, except that only the first match is encapsulated.

What's the best way to go forward?  How do I make R utilize all of the matches available?

Thanks

Comment: RTM! :-) `match` returns a vector of the positions of ***(first)*** matches. You are looking for `%in%`... `Awards$TotalAwarded[ Awards$IDs %in% Proposals$IDs ]`

Comment: Thanks I was under the impression that %in% returned true or false? Also, editing now.

Comment: It does.  But if you vectorize the call, it will return values, not logicals.

Comment: Yup, ok. So how are you going to get the multiple records from Awards to join to Proposal? You are going to have a different number of rows right?

Comment: This example is in no way [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

See help on merge: `?merge`

```
merge( Proposals, Awards, by=ID, all.y=TRUE )
```

But I cannot believe this hasn't been asked on SO before.